# Rails 3: rollback for after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an enrollment form.

When the user enrolls, the app is supposed to save the data in the `enrollments` table and in the `users` table. (I need this separation because the user's profile can change but the data he entered for that particular enrollment has to be archived. So even if later the user changes his last name, in the enrollment form I'll have his initial information.)

So I was thinking about saving data in the `enrollments` table then have a after_create call, like this...

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :save_corresponding_user

  def save_corresponding_user
    user = User.new
    user.full_name = self.user_full_name
    user.email = self.user_email
    user.mobile_phone = self.user_mobile_phone
    user.save
  end
end
```

The issue is, what if saving the user fails for any reason. How can I rollback and destroy the just saved data from the `enrollments` table?

Comment: Can a user enroll several times? If not, I'd just add the extra fields directly in the users table.

Comment: Well,actually, it's a parent/guardian enrolling a kid to a daycare. So yes, the parent can enroll a kid several times.

Comment: To me it seems like putting save_corresponding_user in after_create is going to be an issue.  What happens when the user enrolls again?  You wouldn't want to create a new user object for them.  Also, doesn't the enrollments table probably have a user_id column on it?    That wouldn't be populated in your code above.  If it were me I would just wrap the create of the enrollment and the user in a transaction, which will handle the rolling back of both in the event of an error.

Comment: If the user enrolls again it will validate by `email` or `driver license/id #`. The admins are supposed to know or ask if a person has already enrolled their kids, so instead of going to a First Time Enrollment, they go to the Parent's profile and go to a different form. Yes the `enrollments` table is supposed to have a user_id column, I didn't include a lot of columns in the example for simplicity. I will look into transactions, is there a good tutorial you would recommend? I don't see anything related on the railscasts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

after_create is a part of the transaction saving the current model. Therefore, if your code crashes or if after_create returns false, it should rollback the current transaction and invalidate the `enrollment` saving.

If you want to simulate this, add this to your after_create and see if everything works as expected :

```
raise Exception.new("CRASH")
```

Comment: the rollback doesn't happen if you are using a non transactional database like mongodb

Comment: If after_create returns false doesn't appear to rollback the transaction either (just the exception). At least in Rails 4.

Comment: @djburdick A transaction by default should only rollback if an exception is raised. So this is the expected behavior. I think this answer is slightly incorrect regarding that detail.

Answer (score 13):

Returning `false` from `after_create` will do nothing.

> The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks can only accomplish that by raising an exception.

Also, you must `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback`:

> Any exception that is not ActiveRecord::Rollback will be re-raised by Rails after the callback chain is halted. Raising an exception other than ActiveRecord::Rollback may break code that does not expect methods like save and update_attributes (which normally try to return true or false) to raise an exception.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution

I do something like this:

```
after_create do
  if condition
    errors.add(:attr, 'Blah blah blah.')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

For Rails 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Comment: I found `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` doesn't work but this did : `raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, self` from https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33192

Comment: maybe you're using a different rails version?

Answer (score 1):

As @anthonyalberto mentioned, after_create is already part of the transaction.  To define a transaction you would use something like this in your controller:

```
Enrollment.transaction do
  @enrollment.save!
end
```

That is really all you need to do, if the save of enrollment fails or the save of user fails it will roll back your entire transaction.  Here is more information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

In rails 5, you need to use `throw :abort` to rollback ActiveRecord chain.

[image]

You can see the list of operation handling in different versions of Rails along with before and after callbacks. For better clarification, please look at the concept of halting executions. Please follow the the given link below.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution